Github Actions: Package 'awscli' has no installation candidate
The Github action that we have is failing with following error:
    #7 0.972 Get:11 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security/universe amd64 Packages [9153 B]
  #7 1.082 Get:12 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security/main amd64 Packages [24.8 kB]
  #7 1.608 Fetched 22.2 MB in 1s (15.7 MB/s)
  #7 1.608 Reading package lists...
  #7 2.172 Reading package lists...
  #7 2.718 Building dependency tree...
  #7 2.859 Reading state information...
  #7 2.871 Package awscli is not available, but is referred to by another package.
  #7 2.871 This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
  #7 2.871 is only available from another source
  #7 2.871 
  #7 2.874 E: Package 'awscli' has no installation candidate

I guess the issue is that ubuntu-noble may have removed the awscli from default packages. so i tried to change runs-on to "ubuntu-22.04" the action file to something like this still it didnt fix it:
deploy:
  runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
  needs: [build-and-push]
  steps:
  - uses: actions/checkout@v1
  - uses: chrislennon/action-aws-cli@v1.1
  - run: aws s3 ls
    env:
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
      AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
  - uses: r0zar/sam-deploy-action@v1.4
    env:
      TEMPLATE: 'template.yml'
      AWS_STACK_NAME: '{{secrets.AWS_STACK_NAME}}'
      AWS_REGION: '{{secrets.AWS_REGION}}'
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}}
      AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}}
      AWS_DEPLOY_BUCKET: 'terraform-bucket'

Still this is failing, I am not sure what is the issue.

The ubuntu-22.04 runner already has AWS CLI preinstalled on it. You should use that instead of using https://github.com/chrislennon/action-aws-cli which has been archived. Looks like you're following some old tutorial (the latest actions/checkout version is v4). You should really need to revise and update your workflow.

It seems you need to configure AWS credentials instead of this action chrislennon/action-aws-cli@v1.1
- name: Configure AWS credentials
  uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
  with:
    aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
    aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}

